# A Basic Javascript Todo App Acting Weird In ForLoop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

i was trying to made my own TODO app with HTML,CSS and JS .. everything working as expected , exept this weird problem :

when i add an todo item the forloop will put addEventListener on it , so when i click on it , it will launch any code inside

The Problem : if i create more than one todo item .. some items stop working (addEventListener not working when i click on the item).

its like if i create 1 item:
item1 : working.

if i create 2 items:
item1 : not working.
item2 : working.

if i create 3 items:
item1 : working.
item2 : not working.
item2 : working.
...etc.
any explanation how to fix !

HTML CODE

```
<div id="form">
 <p id="error">Fill The Empty !</p>
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Text Here!" >
  <button id="add" type="submit" onclick="addIt()">Add</button>
</div>  
<div id="listContainer">
  <ul id="list">    

  </ul>
  <p id="noItems">You Have No Items!</p>  
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
list-style: none;
font-size: 10pt;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
#form{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items:center;
}
#error{
color: red;
display: none;
margin: 5px 0px;
}
#input{
width: 95%;
height: 40px;
text-align: center;
margin: 5px 0px;
border: 1px purple dashed;
}
#add{
height: 40px;
width: 95%;
border: 0px;
color: white;
background-color: purple;
font-weight: 900;
}
#add:active{
color: purple;
background-color: white;
}
#listContainer{
margin-top: 40px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 100vw;
}
#list{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column-reverse;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 100vw;
}
.item{
position: relative;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
margin: 5px;
width: 95%;
color: purple;
background-color: white;
border: 1px purple solid;
font-size: 11pt;
}
.delete{
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
padding: 10px;
width: 50px;
color: white;
background-color: red;
font-size: 11pt;
font-weight: 900;
}
#noItems{
color: lightgray;
margin-top: 50px;
/*display: none;*/
}
```

JS CODE

```
let storeInput = "";

function addIt(){
/*---addIT() start---*/
  let input = document.getElementById("input");
  storeInput = input.value;
  if(storeInput == ""){
    let errorMsg = document.getElementById("error");
    errorMsg.style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function(){errorMsg.style.display = "none";}, 2000)
  }else{
    input.value = "";
    let item = document.createElement("LI");
    item.className = "item";
    item.innerHTML = storeInput;
    let list = document.getElementById("list");
    list.appendChild(item); 
    let deleteIt = document.createElement("I");
    deleteIt.className = "delete";
    deleteIt.innerHTML = "X";
    item.appendChild(deleteIt);
  }
  let allItems = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
  for(var i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++){
    allItems[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      if(this.style.textDecoration == "line-through"){
        this.style.textDecoration = "none";
      }else{
        this.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
      }
    })
  }
  let deleteItem = document.querySelectorAll(".delete");
  for(var j = 0; j < deleteItem.length; j++){
    deleteItem[j].addEventListener("click", function(){
      var deleteIt = this.parentElement;
      deleteIt.remove();
    })
  }
  document.querySelectorAll(".item").length;
  if(allItems.length == 0){
    document.getElementById("noItems").style.display = "block";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("noItems").style.display = "none";
  }
/*---addIT() end---*/}
```

if you want to try the app live :
https://codepen.io/Salsa_Project/pen/NVWPaY?editors=0110

AND TY IN ADVANCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function addit() adds eventlisteners to all the items and delete buttons everytime you add an element. You should only add eventlisteners to the current item. [codepen](https://codepen.io/Esger/pen/KLKydM?editors=0110)

```
let storeInput = "";

function addIt(){
/*---addIT() start---*/
  let input = document.getElementById("input");
  storeInput = input.value;
  if(storeInput == ""){
    let errorMsg = document.getElementById("error");
    errorMsg.style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function(){errorMsg.style.display = "none";}, 2000)
  }else{
    input.value = "";
    let item = document.createElement("LI");
    item.className = "item";
    item.innerHTML = storeInput;
    let list = document.getElementById("list");
    list.appendChild(item); 
    let deleteIt = document.createElement("I");
    deleteIt.className = "delete";
    deleteIt.innerHTML = "X";
    item.appendChild(deleteIt);
    item.addEventListener("click", function(){
      if(this.style.textDecoration == "line-through"){
        this.style.textDecoration = "none";
      }else{
        this.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
      }
    });
    deleteIt.addEventListener("click", function(){
      var deleteIt = this.parentElement;
      deleteIt.remove();
    })
  }
  let allItems = document.querySelectorAll(".item");


  document.querySelectorAll(".item").length;
  if(allItems.length == 0){
    document.getElementById("noItems").style.display = "block";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("noItems").style.display = "none";
  }
/*---addIT() end---*/}
```

Comment: please add relevant code to your answer, to exhibit the correct answer

Comment: The editor doesn't accept the code from the pen. nagging about spaces and such

Comment: then link to the pen/jsfiddle whatever

Comment: The link is in there, but the editor doesn't accept it without the backticks around it.

Comment: WOAH now i understund exactly the problem ..Ty

Answer (score 1):

Let us use this snippit for  example

```
  for(var j = 0; j < deleteItem.length; j++){
    deleteItem[j].addEventListener("click", function(){
      var deleteIt = this.parentElement;
      deleteIt.remove();
    })
  }
```

Here, you are running a loop, and  foreach iteration, you are creating a new click event. The issue here is your not unbinding events. So, in your current code, if you click the  button, it will trigger all call events, that were previously triggered.

The quickest solution for your code, is to add something like

```
let deleteItem = document.querySelectorAll(".delete");
  for(var j = 0; j < deleteItem.length; j++){
     deleteItem[j].parentNode.replaceChild(deleteItem[j].cloneNode(true), deleteItem[j]);
    })
  }
 deleteItem = document.querySelectorAll(".delete");
  for(var j = 0; j < deleteItem.length; j++){
    deleteItem[j].addEventListener("click", function(){
      var deleteIt = this.parentElement;
      deleteIt.remove();
    })
  }
```

Note that

```
  for(var j = 0; j < deleteItem.length; j++){
     deleteItem[j].parentNode.replaceChild(deleteItem[j].cloneNode(true), deleteItem[j]);
    })
  }
```

Will replace your current element, with itself. The only differenceis, cloneNode, does not copy the event listeners. This fixes your problem.

Comment: ty too for such detailed explanation